# How do I declare a Multidimensional Array of a given size in Typescript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, typescript

I have the following...

```
export class Puzzle {
  pieces : Piece[];
  orderedPieces : Piece[][];
  constructor(width: number, height: number){
    this.height = height, this.width = width;
    let total : number = width * height;
    this.pieces = new Array<Piece>(total);
    this.orderedPieces = new Piece[height][width]; // Doesn't work what do I put here?
  }
  ...
}
```

How would I declare something like this in Typescript?

Error is...

> Cannot read property '2' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (that I'm aware of) to instantiate a multidimensional array in javascript in one line.
You'll have to actually create all of the arrays yourself, something like:

```
this.orderedPieces = new Array(this.height);

for (let i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
    this.orderedPieces[i] = new Array(this.width);
}
```

Comment: What if it is typed as I have above?

Comment: It works well for me with your code. Is there a problem or an error for you?